# cannot receive file using asmack

Tags: android

I am unable to receieve file using asmack but i was able to send file.
Below is the code for receiving file,please tell me what am I doing wrong

```
             ServiceDiscoveryManager serv=  new ServiceDiscoveryManager(ConnectionActivity.m_connection);
    FileTransferManager manger=new FileTransferManager(ConnectionActivity.m_connection);
    manger.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener(){

        @Override
        public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v("request", "accept");
            IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
            transfer=request.accept();
            Log.v("status",transfer.getStatus()+"");
            Log.v("filename",transfer.getFileName()+"");//im able to get filename
            File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/off","downloaded");
            try {
                transfer.recieveFile(file);
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```
// //File transfer
pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si",
        new StreamInitiationProvider());
pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams",
        new BytestreamsProvider());
pm.addIQProvider("open", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb",
        new OpenIQProvider());
pm.addIQProvider("close", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb",
        new CloseIQProvider());
pm.addExtensionProvider("data", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb",
        new DataPacketProvider());
```

Comment: I am currently not working on asmack, so I cannot confirm. If somebody tried this and its working please let me know so that i can mark it

Answer (score 0):

```
configureProviderManager(connection);

    FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);
    FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("hariom@jabber.ccc.de/Smack");

    File file = new File("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1385869353956.jpg");
    try {
        Log.d("file sending",file.getAbsolutePath()+" "+file.getName());
        configureProviderManager(connection);
       transfer.sendFile(file, "test_file");
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(!transfer.isDone()) {
           if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error)) {
              System.out.println("ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());
           } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.cancelled)
                            || transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.refused)) {
              System.out.println("Cancelled!!! " + transfer.getError());
           }
           try {
              Thread.sleep(1000L);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }

        if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.refused))
                 System.out.println("refused  " + transfer.getError());
        else if( transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error))
             System.out.println(" error " + transfer.getError());
        else if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.cancelled))
           System.out.println(" cancelled  " + transfer.getError());
        else
           System.out.println("Success");
```

below is code to adjust provider manager

```
public void configureProviderManager(XMPPConnection connection) {


    ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
    ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
    ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());



    ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams",
            new BytestreamsProvider());
    ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items",
            new DiscoverItemsProvider());
    ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info",
            new DiscoverInfoProvider());

    ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    if (sdm == null)
        sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);

    sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
    sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#item");
    sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");


    ProviderManager pm = ProviderManager.getInstance();

    // The order is the same as in the smack.providers file

    //  Private Data Storage
    pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:private", new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());
    //  Time
    try {
        pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:time", Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time");
    }

    //  Roster Exchange
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:roster", new RosterExchangeProvider());
    //  Message Events
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:event", new MessageEventProvider());
    //  Chat State
    pm.addExtensionProvider("active","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("composing","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("paused","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("inactive","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("gone","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

    //  XHTML
    pm.addExtensionProvider("html","http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im", new XHTMLExtensionProvider());

    //  Group Chat Invitations
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:conference", new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());
    //  Service Discovery # Items
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
    //  Service Discovery # Info
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());
    //  Data Forms
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());
    //  MUC User
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user", new MUCUserProvider());
    //  MUC Admin
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin", new MUCAdminProvider());
    //  MUC Owner
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner", new MUCOwnerProvider());
    //  Delayed Delivery
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:delay", new DelayInformationProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("delay", "urn:xmpp:delay", new DelayInformationProvider());
    //  Version
    try {
        pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:version", Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version");
    }
    //  VCard
    pm.addIQProvider("vCard","vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());
    //  Offline Message Requests
    pm.addIQProvider("offline","http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());
    //  Offline Message Indicator
    pm.addExtensionProvider("offline","http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());
    //  Last Activity
    pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:last", new LastActivity.Provider());
    //  User Search
    pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());
    //  SharedGroupsInfo
    pm.addIQProvider("sharedgroup","http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup", new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());

    //  JEP-33: Extended Stanza Addressing
    pm.addExtensionProvider("addresses","http://jabber.org/protocol/address", new MultipleAddressesProvider());

    //   FileTransfer
    pm.addIQProvider("si","http://jabber.org/protocol/si", new StreamInitiationProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("open","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new OpenIQProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("data","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new DataPacketProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("close","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new CloseIQProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("data","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new DataPacketProvider());

    //  Privacy
    pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:privacy", new PrivacyProvider());

    // SHIM
    pm.addExtensionProvider("headers", "http://jabber.org/protocol/shim", new HeadersProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("header", "http://jabber.org/protocol/shim", new HeaderProvider());

    // PubSub
    pm.addIQProvider("pubsub", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new PubSubProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("create", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new SimpleNodeProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("items", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new ItemsProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("item", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new ItemProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("subscriptions", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new SubscriptionsProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("subscription", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new SubscriptionProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("affiliations", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new AffiliationsProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("affiliation", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new AffiliationProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("options", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub", new FormNodeProvider());
    // PubSub owner
    pm.addIQProvider("pubsub", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner", new PubSubProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("configure", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner", new FormNodeProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("default", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner", new FormNodeProvider());
    // PubSub event
    pm.addExtensionProvider("event", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new EventProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("configuration", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new ConfigEventProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("delete", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new SimpleNodeProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("options", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new FormNodeProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("items", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new ItemsProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("item", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new ItemProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("retract", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new RetractEventProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("purge", "http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event", new SimpleNodeProvider());

    // Nick Exchange
    pm.addExtensionProvider("nick", "http://jabber.org/protocol/nick", new Nick.Provider());

    // Attention
    pm.addExtensionProvider("attention", "urn:xmpp:attention:0", new AttentionExtension.Provider());

    //input
    pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si",
            new StreamInitiationProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams",
            new BytestreamsProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("open", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb",
            new OpenIQProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("close", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb",
            new CloseIQProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("data", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb",
            new DataPacketProvider());

}
```